# Stop execution of process when app is quit

Tags: ios, multithreading, exit

I have an app where the user can initiate a refresh and I want to build things correctly to handle things like the app quitting, a phone call, home button, etc. If the user hits the home button in the middle of the process now, when they reopen the app, it keeps going. I'm not sure I want this. I would like the home button to kill that process and have them start things over when they reopen. Whats the best way to stop what you're doing so to speak (i understand i need to use didenterbackground and the inverse). This process should be on a background thread so i could NSThread cancel? Ive read about periodically checking a flag, but then how do i stop once i detect the condition? It made me curious, and I'm sure it's simple, but what the best way is to simply stop execution of something.

Answer (score 1):

From Apple's [**Thread Programming Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/CreatingThreads/CreatingThreads.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH15-SW10) (Thread management -> Terminating a thread):

> Although Cocoa, POSIX, and Multiprocessing Services offer routines for killing threads directly, the use of such routines is strongly discouraged. Killing a thread prevents that thread from cleaning up after itself. **Memory allocated by the thread could potentially be leaked and any other resources currently in use by the thread might not be cleaned up properly, creating potential problems later**.
>
> If you anticipate the need to terminate a thread in the middle of an operation, you should design your threads from the outset to respond to a cancel or exit message. For long-running operations, this might mean stopping work periodically and checking to see if such a message arrived. If a message does come in asking the thread to exit, the thread would then have the opportunity to perform any needed cleanup and exit gracefully; otherwise, it could simply go back to work and process the next chunk of data.

And it has also example code how to do this:

```
- (void)threadMainRoutine
{
    BOOL moreWorkToDo = YES;
    BOOL exitNow = NO;
    NSRunLoop* runLoop = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
 
    // Add the exitNow BOOL to the thread dictionary.
    NSMutableDictionary* threadDict = [[NSThread currentThread] threadDictionary];
    [threadDict setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:exitNow] forKey:@"ThreadShouldExitNow"];
 
    // Install an input source.
    [self myInstallCustomInputSource];
 
    while (moreWorkToDo && !exitNow)
    {
        // Do one chunk of a larger body of work here.
        // Change the value of the moreWorkToDo Boolean when done.
 
        // Run the run loop but timeout immediately if the input source isn't waiting to fire.
        [runLoop runUntilDate:[NSDate date]];
 
        // Check to see if an input source handler changed the exitNow value.
        exitNow = [[threadDict valueForKey:@"ThreadShouldExitNow"] boolValue];
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks so much for the response. i had seen this posted elsewhere, but it confused me a little and i was wondering if i can't do something similar. it certainly seems like i should avoid canceling the thread and use the bool flag periodically check mechanism, but if i have a check and i determine the action needs to stop, a return stops things, but how does that affect the thread itself? as a general question, if nothing is running, or it gets to the end of the code, will the thread close itself?

Answer (score 0):

Create a `NSOperationQueue`. For all your long running tasks, create `NSOperation` objects, put them on the `NSOperationQueue`. You can detect when the app is going into the background by using the app delegate's `applicationWillResignActive` method, or the `UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification` notification.

When you detect a state transition, simply call your queue's `cancelAllOperations` method. There's also a `suspended` property on the queue, if you'd rather just pause it.  (And you can resume it later.)

NSOperationQueue is fantastic technology.  Much higher level than GCD. Learn it, love it!